# Found unknown Linux distribution on /dev/sdb2: grub configuration dual boot Arch Linux and NetBSD-7.0

Tags: archlinux, grub, netbsd

I have Arch Linux on `/dev/sdb1` and NetBSD-7.0 on `/dev/sdb2`.

On Arch Linux when I run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` I get a message like `Found unknown Linux distribution on /dev/sdb2` but when I reboot, there is no grub option for that unknown Linux distribution which I know it is NetBSD-7.0.

How can I add NetBSD-7.0 to my grub menu option when rebooting.

There is a similar [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109272/add-freebsd-to-grub2-boot-menu), currently looking into it.

UPDATE: I mounted NetBSD partition with `sudo mount -t ufs -o ro,ufstype=ufs2 /dev/sdb2 /mnt/` (`ufstype=44bsd` did not work) and then ran `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` but yet the issue persists.

UPDATE: Rebooted and pressed `c` to get the grub command line. Following commands booted the NetBSD-7.0:

```
ls
```

Ran `ls` to see the correct name of disks and partitions, `/dev/sdb2` on Linux was `(hd0,gpt2)` on Grub. Then ran the following:

```
insmod ufs2
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
knetbsd /netbsd
boot
```

And NetBSD-7.0 booted.

To add NetBSD option to Grub menu, modified file `/etc/grub/40_custom` on Arch Linux like below:

```
menuentry "NetBSD-7.0"{
insmod ufs2
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
knetbsd /netbsd
}
```

**However**, after modifying `40_custom` like above, NetBSD option does not appear on Grub menu. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Unless you have a typo, it looks like the 40_custom file is in the wrong directory. it should be located at `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, notice the `.d`.
- If your `/boot` is located on a separate partition, make sure that it is mounted with `mount /boot` before generating the grub.cfg. Otherwise your new grub.cfg won't be used.
- Check which partition grub is loading the configuration from by running `echo ${prefix}` within the grub command line. It's possible that grub is loading the configuration from a partition that you don't expect.
- Verify that netbsd was added to the config with `grep -i netbsd /boot/grub/grub.cfg` before rebooting to avoid some frustration after generating grub.cfg